# Need to know the point of authentication rejection in this Radius debug log

Tags: radius, edirectory

Running Radius 2.1.7 on SLES 11 SP2, configured to use LDAP authentication and "dialup access=true"

My own userID can authenticate just fine, and it is part of the radius password policy. Another user using the same password policy is unable to authenticate.  Can someone help me figure out what is EAP-TLV failure?

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 140.10.85.4 port 1645, id=57, length=221
        User-Name = "mohdfariza"
        Framed-MTU = 1400
        Called-Station-Id = "0013.7f43.9f50"
        Calling-Station-Id = "a816.b25f.54af"
        Service-Type = Login-User
        Message-Authenticator = 0x7c15082e8992a6640cc3d795a2c78840
        EAP-Message = 0x020a0050190017030100209f86cd5e851f3ea74981a4ac0356d9c406296f83a59103bdd53f3b39692528c81703010020e373b0a84183b081bd64acb67ef81941af5e4edd8d1ad2d71a32ae825151890b
        NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
        NAS-Port = 302
        State = 0x4ca99e914ba38777aa4e9129995c242d
        NAS-IP-Address = 140.10.85.4
        NAS-Identifier = "ict-dev"
+- entering group authorize {...}
++[preprocess] returns ok
[auth_log]      expand: /var/log/radius/radacct/%{Client-IP-Address}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d -> /var/log/radius/radacct/140.10.85.4/auth-detail-20131107
[auth_log] /var/log/radius/radacct/%{Client-IP-Address}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d expands to /var/log/radius/radacct/140.10.85.4/auth-detail-20131107
[auth_log]      expand: %t -> Thu Nov  7 13:53:01 2013
++[auth_log] returns ok
++[mschap] returns noop
[eap] EAP packet type response id 10 length 80
[eap] Continuing tunnel setup.
++[eap] returns ok
[ldap] performing user authorization for mohdfariza
[ldap] WARNING: Deprecated conditional expansion ":-".  See "man unlang" for details
[ldap]  expand: (uid=%{Stripped-User-Name:-%{User-Name}}) -> (uid=mohdfariza)
[ldap]  expand: o=syabas -> o=syabas
rlm_ldap: ldap_get_conn: Checking Id: 0
rlm_ldap: ldap_get_conn: Got Id: 0
rlm_ldap: performing search in o=syabas, with filter (uid=mohdfariza)
[ldap] checking if remote access for mohdfariza is allowed by dialupAccess
[ldap] Added the eDirectory password ejat5177 in check items as Cleartext-Password
[ldap] No default NMAS login sequence
[ldap] looking for check items in directory...
rlm_ldap: sambaNtPassword -> NT-Password == 0x4143333936454137334544373432433830304436323445314141354644464444
[ldap] looking for reply items in directory...
[ldap] user mohdfariza authorized to use remote access
rlm_ldap: ldap_release_conn: Release Id: 0
++[ldap] returns ok
[pap] Normalizing NT-Password from hex encoding
[pap] Found existing Auth-Type, not changing it.
++[pap] returns noop
Found Auth-Type = EAP
+- entering group authenticate {...}
[eap] Request found, released from the list
[eap] EAP/peap
[eap] processing type peap
[peap] processing EAP-TLS
[peap] eaptls_verify returned 7
[peap] Done initial handshake
[peap] eaptls_process returned 7
[peap] EAPTLS_OK
[peap] Session established.  Decoding tunneled attributes.
[peap] Received EAP-TLV response.
[peap]  Had sent TLV failure.  User was rejected earlier in this session.
[eap] Handler failed in EAP/peap
[eap] Failed in EAP select
++[eap] returns invalid
Failed to authenticate the user.
Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
  WARNING: Unknown value specified for Post-Auth-Type.  Cannot perform requested action.
Delaying reject of request 26 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
Waking up in 0.4 seconds.
Cleaning up request 9 ID 40 with timestamp +51
Cleaning up request 10 ID 41 with timestamp +51
Cleaning up request 11 ID 42 with timestamp +51
Cleaning up request 12 ID 43 with timestamp +51
Waking up in 0.1 seconds.
Cleaning up request 13 ID 44 with timestamp +52
Cleaning up request 14 ID 45 with timestamp +52
Cleaning up request 15 ID 46 with timestamp +52
Cleaning up request 16 ID 47 with timestamp +52
Sending delayed reject for request 26
Sending Access-Reject of id 57 to 140.10.85.4 port 1645
        EAP-Message = 0x040a0004
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Cleaning up request 17 ID 48 with timestamp +52
Waking up in 2.5 seconds.
Cleaning up request 18 ID 49 with timestamp +55
Cleaning up request 19 ID 50 with timestamp +55
Cleaning up request 20 ID 51 with timestamp +55
Cleaning up request 21 ID 52 with timestamp +55
Waking up in 0.1 seconds.
Cleaning up request 22 ID 53 with timestamp +56
Cleaning up request 23 ID 54 with timestamp +56
Cleaning up request 24 ID 55 with timestamp +56
Cleaning up request 25 ID 56 with timestamp +56
Waking up in 1.0 seconds.
Cleaning up request 26 ID 57 with timestamp +56
Ready to process requests.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Radius needs to be able to retrieve the Universal Password.  If something is not correct there, it will fail.  That you, and this user are in the same password policy is a good sign as it means the same rules apply and should work for both.

Test that the user is properly configured with Universal Password with this tool:

[Jim Willeke's DumpUp tool](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/Wiki.jsp?page=DumpEdirectoryPasswordInformationTool)